# Is the use of would with a stative verb to express past states ok in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is the use of *would* correct in this sentence?

> We didn't use to have modern equipment but we were very skilled and I **would** be really happy when my patients got well again.

Comment: "I'd **feel** happy" might improve. *Would be* as a phrase seems to be the problem.

Comment: This sentence is from the English language textbook in the Syrian schools. The rule says that _would_ cannot be used with stative verbs to express past states, and then one finds this sentence in the same lesson. It is confusing for both the teacher and the students, and I need to know if this sentence is grammatical or ungrammatical please.

Answer (score 1):

"Used to" is more correct in this context. Would is better reserved for non-stative verbs.

Comment: Is it wrong like this?

Comment: For example: I would cry with delight when my patients got well again.

Comment: That would be OK, in my opinion